# SQL Server : JSON

Tags: json, sql-server

Please help me to get records for below JSON String, 1 record for each skill

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(1000);

SET @json = '{"name":"John","surname":"Doe","age":45,"skills":["SQL","C#","MVC"]}';
```

Required output is :

```
NAME SURNAME AGE SKILL 
JOHN DOE 45 SQL
JOHN DOE 45 C#
JOHN DOE 45 MVC
```

What I am trying :

**Step 1**:

Created a table

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(1000);

SET @json = '{"name":"John","surname":"Doe","age":45,"skills":["SQL","C#","MVC"]}';

INSERT INTO student 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
    WITH (
             name varchar(100) ,
             surname varchar(100) ,
             age int,
             skills nvarchar(max) as json
         );
```

**Step 2**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student s
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(skills) WITH (skills nvarchar(max)) AS j
```

but, by doing this, what I am getting is:

```
NAME  SURNAME  AGE   SKILL 
--------------------------
JOHN  DOE      45    NULL
JOHN  DOE      45    NULL
JOHN  DOE      45    NULL
```

Comment: There are code formatting options in the text editor for a reason. Please don't use HTML to try to format your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no key `skills` in your JSON data in the column `skills` in the table, `students`. The keys are unnamed, so you need to reference `value`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(1000);
SET @json = N'{"name":"John","surname":"Doe","age":45,"skills":["SQL","C#","MVC"]}';

SELECT P.name,
       P.surname,
       P.age,
       S.value AS skill
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
        WITH (name varchar(100),
              surname varchar(100),
              age int,
              skills nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) P
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.skills) S;
```

Comment: Ohhhhh great . 
it is that simple and i have successfully wasted my 2-3 hours for this.by searching on other forums ..
Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: @SarveshBandekar, mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future